# transmission-daemon ignoring settings.json

Tags: server, services, transmission

Since I upgraded my ubuntu server installation from 16.04 to 16.10, the transmission-daemon service seems to be ignoring `settings.json`.

The symptom is that the web interface gives me:

```
403: Forbidden

Unauthorized IP Address.

Either disable the IP address whitelist or add your address to it.

If you're editing settings.json, see the 'rpc-whitelist' and 'rpc-whitelist-enabled' entries.
```

but in `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` we have, unchanged from before the upgrade:

```
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.23.*",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
```

`/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json` also points to `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`:

```
jast@achilles:/etc/transmission-daemon$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Sep  5 12:56 settings.json -> /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

syslog after doing `service transmission-daemon restart` (I think it should usually be also tellung me what ips it adds to the whitelist:

```
Jan  7 13:16:37 achilles transmission-daemon[4087]: Closing transmission session... done.
Jan  7 13:16:38 achilles transmission-daemon[5025]: [2017-01-07 13:16:38.552] UDP Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 425984 (tr-udp.c:84)
Jan  7 13:16:38 achilles transmission-daemon[5025]: [2017-01-07 13:16:38.552] UDP Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 425984 (tr-udp.c:95)
Jan  7 13:16:38 achilles transmission-daemon[5025]: [2017-01-07 13:16:38.552] UDP Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 425984 (tr-udp.c:84)
Jan  7 13:16:38 achilles transmission-daemon[5025]: [2017-01-07 13:16:38.552] UDP Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 425984 (tr-udp.c:95)
```

So where is it trying to get its config from now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After updating 16.04 LTS, systemd would not load my config file for transmission-daemon from the correct location.

I found a workaround at: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734467

I tried the drop-in *.conf file in /etc/systemd/system/transmission.service.d/ to override ExecStart. However, using ps -ef | grep transmission I could see the  wrong config location was still being used after reloads and restarts.

Reluctantly, I edited

```
/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
```

to include the correct path by appending

```
-g /etc/transmission-daemon
```

to the ExecStart line.

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=debian-transmission
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -g /etc/transmission-daemon
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This is on the right track but an unsustainable overkill. See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1138789/151158 for a simpler and idiomatic approach.

Comment: The problem stills happening on transmission-daemon/stable,stable 2.94-2+deb10u2 amd64 (debian 10) but your solution too :)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem just now; `transmission-daemon.service` decided to ignore my `rpc-whitelist` for whatever reason after I changed the user of the daemon. Jim Ladd's answer above is somewhat on the right track but editing systemd config files under `/lib/systemd` is a really bad idea because those edits wouldn't survive package upgrades. The correct way to edit a systemd config is to use `systemd edit foo.service` (which creates an override file in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d` that works in conjunction with the existing config) or `systemd edit --full foo.service` (which creates `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service` that completely replaces the `/lib/systemd/` version). To replace the `ExecStart` line, your override file should look like this:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=  # Clear existing ExecStart
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -g /etc/transmission-daemon
```

Note however that overriding `ExecStart` isn't even necessary. `transmission-daemon` recognizes the `TRANSMISSION_HOME` env var, which works the same as `-g, --config-dir`. So, an easier override:

```
# A simpler and more robust /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=TRANSMISSION_HOME=/etc/transmission-daemon
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! I also had to add a line defining the user in override.conf, since I'm running Transmission using a different user than standard: User=username.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. @JimLadd's answer worked for me but I just wanted to add that you need to restart the daemon after editing the file using:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after latest apt update losing location of config file with:

Description:    Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (development branch)

Release:        22.04

Instructions from this site:

[Install Transmission Bittorrent Client on Ubuntu 15.x](https://www.htpcguides.com/install-transmission-bittorrent-client-on-ubuntu-15-x/)

Modify the transmission systemd script variables to use the right settings.json file (updated and fixed)

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/local.conf
```

Add these lines to /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/local.conf:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -g /etc/transmission-daemon
```

Ctrl+X, Y and Enter to Save

thanks to Alessandro for the suggestion.

Comment: Hello. Since Ubuntu 22.04 does not exist yet this can not be an answer. Sorry.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish will be released on April 21, 2022.  I'm currently running the development branch as I stated in my post.  I'm not having any issues with running the latest version of TransmissionBT after following the instructions I found and noted. in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue since I installed on 16.04, while it was previously working fine on 14.04.
Check this out: http://www.htpcguides.com/install-transmission-bittorrent-client-on-ubuntu-15-x/ - steps #4, #5 and #6. Basically you need to modify the systemd script variables.
I know this is something that has changed from 14.04 to 16.04, so shouldn't apply to you if was working before, but is worth a try.

Comment: can you - for future reference in case the cited source is changed/removed - please add a relevant excerpt from your link?