# How does transmission-daemon work ? Download don't seem to start

Tags: command-line, bash, bittorrent, transmission

I installed transmission-daemon in order to have a command-line torrent downloader which I could access through SSH. My problem is that I am struggling to understand how to use it.

I have run `transmission-daemon -c $HOME/TorrentFiles` in order to set a folder to watch for new .torrent files

I have run `transmission-daemon -w $HOME/Downloads` to set the destination folder of downloaded files

As soon as I add a torrent file to the TorrentFiles folder, the extension .added is added, **but the download of the torrents don't seem to begin !!**

How to make it work ??

Thanks in advance !!

--

EDIT : It seems like the daemon does not start automatically the download and I'm supposed to run either `transmission-remote -s` or click on a button from the web interface. But I can't do it **for authentication reasons** (on the web interface, I get a 403 Error) : I've tried to edit `.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`, but it doesn't help modifying `"rpc-whitelist"`'s value to `"127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*"` nor setting `"rpc-whitelist-enabled"` to `false`.

PS : `rpc-authentication-required` is already false.

PS : Obviously, I have stopped the daemon before editing and started it again afterwards.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `transmission-daemon`, but those commands doesn't seem to actually *start* the downloads, but only set watch and download directory. You still have to start the downloads via  transmission's web interface or with `transmission-remote -s`. If that helps please mention me (@dessert) and I'll make it an answer. You can find further help on the topic on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo#Command_Line_Interface).

Comment: Thank you @dessert for the clue. But well, I'm trying to access the web interface at 192.168.178.43:9091 in my case (local IP), but it seems like I haven't got the rights for (403 Error). I've tried to edit `.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`, but it doesn't help modifying "rpc-whitelist"'s value to "127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*" nor setting "rpc-whitelist-enabled" to false. And using transmission-remote, I don't achieve anything.

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments. Does `transmission-remote -s` show any error?

Comment: Yes : it says `No torrent specified! Please use the -t option first.` And on a second line, there's `Unexpected response: <h1>401: Unauthorized</h1>Unauthorized User`. Obviously, I've tried to figure out how to use the -t option and how to authenticate, but nothing works. PS @dessert : I will add additional info to my original post in a few seconds. Sorry about that.

Comment: For the next one who would read this, maybe this could help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/869046/transmission-daemon-ignoring-settings-json?rq=1 - I will test that this evening; if it works, I'll make an answer.

Comment: This link helped me out of my problem : https://www.htpcguides.com/install-transmission-bittorrent-client-on-ubuntu-15-x/