# transmission-daemon configuration not working

Tags: permissions, configuration, services, transmission

I am trying to access transmission-daemon over HTTP. I have thus edited the `rpc-whitelist` option in `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`. I *did* stop and restart the daemon while editing the config.

From here, transmission-daemon is not updating with the new configuration settings.

```
"rpc-enabled": true,
"rpc-host-whitelist": "",
"rpc-host-whitelist-enabled": true,
"rpc-password": "********",
"rpc-port": 9091,
"rpc-url": "/transmission/",
"rpc-username": "nulrie",
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.0.*",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
```

I have `rm`ed `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`, I have edited `transmission-daemon.service` according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869046/transmission-daemon-ignoring-settings-json), but no solutions are coming to fruition.

What more can I try to get this  to work?

Host: 192.168.0.142
Accessing client: 192.168.0.226

The actual error:
`403 forbidden` @ http://192.168.0.142:9091/transmission/

Comment: Either `transmission-cli` or `transmission-common` was causing an issue with a config. Previously purged transmission-daemon but this did not resolve the issue. Purging all 3 then reinstalling resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Either `transmission-cli` or `transmission-common` was causing an issue with a config. Previously purged transmission-daemon but this did not resolve the issue. Purging all 3 then reinstalling resolved.